# Are questions about Product Management on or off topic?

Tags: discussion

A new area 51 proposal just started for [Product Management](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28281/product-management).  I don't see much difference and have [already asked this question](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/548/how-is-product-management-different-from-project-management) there.  Frankly, I don't see much difference. What ultimately differentiates a team created to launch a product, versus one organized around a project with the goal of creating or launching a product? It seems to be a difference in perspective.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Product Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_management) and [Project Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management) are very similar.

Product Management seems to have more of a focus on marketing in the product lifecycle, but like Project Management, it involves coordinating between several departments and resources to meet product/project goals.

Due to the similarities, my suggestion is that Product Management questions be included and that a `Product Management` tag be created for those questions, should they ever need to be moved to their own site.

Comment: +1 sounds like a good approach.

Answer (score 4):

I am a product manager and have looked around this site and feel that a separate SE for Product Management would be better if there is enough support for it - [Area 51 Proposal for Product Management](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28281/product-management?referrer=zsgkZlKKjIbzSD_x4FjuCA2).

Comment: Sometimes it's best to keep a site merged so that the community is large enough to succeed while other times it makes sense to split them. Is the Product Management community large enough to stand on it's own? If Project Management SE stopped accepting those Product Management questions, what would our questions per day be? Would it still be high enough to leave Beta?

Comment: I am now following the proposal. I must admit the questions asked there *are* different than the ones asked here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm too late, but I don't think that product management is a good subject to discuss in our site. Mostly because it relates to areas absolutely outside of project management scope. Consider the example. A team develops a custom iPhone application and sells it on the market. Product manager in this team would be responsible for the product itself, its quality, its marketing characteristics, its promotion planning, customer satisfaction, etc.

We merely can't enlighten all these topics on our site. Or we will talk about them in a very non-professional manner.

Answer (score 0):

### When "Product Management" Intersects "Project Management"

This is an old question, but here's an updated take on the question based on several years of PMSE experience.

1. Product management *as a discipline* is generally outside the scope of a site focused on project management.
2. Product management questions may be considered on-topic here when they directly intersect the project management discipline, e.g. when they're about how a Product Manager works with the project team.
3. Questions about the Product Owner role within agile frameworks like Scrum or Nexus are generally accepted as on-topic because they're explicitly defined roles within those project management methodologies.

A good rule of thumb is that a product management question is on-topic here only insofar as it relates to the field or practice of *project* management. Product management questions about marketing, business intelligence, sales, and so forth will generally remain out of scope from a *project management* standpoint.