# Product Management questions - 2020 edition

Tags: discussion, site-topic, questions

Seems that roughly every 5 years (as [HERE](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/430) and [HERE](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/721/430)) this conversation is triggered:

"Are Product Management questions on or off-topic at PM.SE?"

Answer (score 4):

As it stands, the best (and latest) answer for this question is available on [THIS ANSWER](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/723/430) from Todd.

I share the **TL;DR** excerpt here:

> Product management as it relates to project management is certainly
> on-topic here, but other aspects of product or portfolio management
> are out of scope. In particular, the roles and responsibilities of a
> Product Manager within a given project-management framework are likely
> to be very much within the scope of this site.

The [on-topic](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) session of our community has been expanded to make it explicitly clear.